# "No resource type specified (at 'icon' with value '@favorites')" - with use Victor library

Tags: android, menu

Please help with this problem.
I use [Victor](https://github.com/trello/victor) library and I have problem when i want use menu item

With this library I would next - "With this plugin, you can define source folders for SVGs and they will automatically be rasterized/included in your build without messing with your source code."

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/catalog"
        android:icon="@drawable/catalog_not_selected"
        android:title="Catalog" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/favorites"
        android:icon="@favorites_not_selected"
        android:title="Favorites" />
</menu>`
```

Part with my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.trello.victor'
android {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            svg.srcDir 'src/main/svg'
        }
    }
victor {
    svgDpi = 32
    excludeDensities = [ 'mdpi', 'xxxhdpi' ]
    generateVectorDrawables = false
}
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

Code where I want use it:

```
        mBottomBar.setOnTabSelectListener(new OnTabSelectListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(@IdRes int tabId) {
                if (tabId == R.id.catalog) {
                    mBottomBar.setItems(R.menu.bottombar_tabs_catalog);
                    //mBottomBar.setItems(sResource[0][1]);
                }
                if (tabId == R.id.favorites) {
                    mBottomBar.setItems(R.menu.bottombar_tabs_favorites);
                }
            }
        });
```